# Stack Base Memory Address

Tags: gcc, arm, embedded, cortex-m

Is there a simple way to find the stack base pointer programmatically? I am coding for an STM32F4 microcontroller and compiling with arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler.

When I was using the Arm C compiler packaged with Keil uVision 5 I could use the ABI function `__user_initial_stackheap()` to retrieve the stack base, but that doesn't seem to work with gcc.

Comment: there is no general answer to this question since it depends on what startup code you are using. This defines the stack area and probably also exports a global symbol with it's address.

Comment: It appears you are correct. I found a solution by referencing linker script variables. Will post my solution as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how the different memory sections are set up (typically in a linker script). For instance, the linker script for an STM32F4 may define the stack base as:

```
__stack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);
```

Then the linker script variables can be accessed in C code with

```
extern uint32_t __stack;

void foo() {
  uint32_t stack_base = &__stack;
}
```